# How to resolve: TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not builtin_function_or_method

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

pygame.init()

size = (800, 625)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Game of Ur")
Token = pygame.image.load("chip.png").convert
board = pygame.image.load("board.png").convert

done = False


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    screen.blit(board,[0,0])

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)


pygame.quit()
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ed\Documents\thonk\game.py", line 43, in <module>
  screen.blit(board,[0,0])
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not builtin_function_or_method
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a good hint. `board` is a function or method. Looking to where its assigned,

```
board = pygame.image.load("board.png").convert
```

ah! That's a method and you need to call it to get the board. Same issue with Token. Simply fixing those two lines does it

```
import pygame

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

pygame.init()

size = (800, 625)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Game of Ur")
Token = pygame.image.load("chip.png").convert()
board = pygame.image.load("board.png").convert()
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    screen.blit(board,[0,0])
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```